# Excel 50% Proportion Formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to figure out the formula for a 50% proportion of a numbers.

Given the following set of numbers, is there a way to calculate the number that represents 50%?

[image: Excel Numbers]

I am using the following formula to get the %

```
=COUNTIF(A$1:A$13,">="&A1)/COUNT(A$1:A$13)
```

Notes:

- I would expect the number to be 8.5
- I am not looking for the Median
- I am looking for a formula that takes the whole array and gives answers similar to "If Y = 50% then X" (in the example above, X = 8.5) or eventually "If Y% then X"
- I also eventually want the inverse, figuring out % based on a known number: "If X = 8.5 then Y% = ?"

Comment: What number would you expect as your output? 7, 10, or a floating point number in between? Or have I misunderstood completely?

Comment: 50% of what? Your formula does not make sense. Please ignore any formula that does not work anyway and describe in words what you would like to achieve.

Comment: Are you looking for `MEDIAN()`??

Comment: Can you explain how the current % values are calculated, is it absolute or cumulative%?

Comment: Jonno- edits made to the question: floating number, I would expect 8.5

Comment: teylyn- The formula I gave works. Additional notes given.

Comment: Wouldn't 8.5 returns `46.2%`? 6 of the 13 numbers in the array are greater than or equal to 8.5, so the formula would return `6/13`. If you mean for the 50% value to be included in the array as well (i.e., let it be a 14th number in the array), then any number between 7 and 10 would return `50%`; 8.5 just happens to be in the middle of that range. That said, what exactly are you trying to calculate? Until you have it clear and have stated it, no one's going to be able to help you.

Comment: You're looking for some form of interpolation, but you haven't really defined the basis on which that should be done.  For example, find the points above and below the target and use linear interpolation between those two?  Base it on the curve described by all of the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use a simple **linear interpolation** between the values in row #7 and the values in row #8.

The interpolation formula is:

[image]

In **D6** enter the formula for the *slope*:

```
=(A8-A7)/(B8-B7)
```

In **D7** enter the formula for the *intercept*:

```
=A8-D6*B8
```

Finally, in **D9** enter the linear formula:

```
=D6*(0.5)+D7
```

This yields ***8.5***:

[image]

Comment: This is getting much closer to the answer. I didn't have a name for it, but linear interpolation is exactly what I am trying to figure out. The difference in this answer vs what I am looking for is that I need to use this in large arrays. The formula should select the whole array.

Comment: Using your info, I was able to find some more info. One example is: http://peltiertech.com/excel-interpolation-formulas/ This seems to be the answer

Comment: @Cascades  **Do you need more help ??**

Comment: No your answer led me to the right answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Using Gary's point that this is linear interpolation (which helped me answer my question), I researched further and found the ultimate answer:

If I want to find out the # based on a known % I use the following:

```
B:Array =COUNTIF(A$5:A$17,">="&A5)/COUNT(A$5:A$17)
B3: =MATCH(B2,B5:B17,-1)
A2: =INDEX(A5:A17,B3) + (B2-INDEX(B5:B17,B3)) * (INDEX(A5:A17,B3+1)-INDEX(A5:A17,B3)) / (INDEX(B5:B17,B3+1)-INDEX(B5:B17,B3))
B2: =ANSWER
```

[Excel Answer #](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIdYR.jpg)

---

If I want to find out the # based on a known % I use the following:

```
B:Array =COUNTIF(A$5:A$17,">="&A5)/COUNT(A$5:A$17)
B3: =MATCH(A2,A5:A17)
A2: =INDEX(B5:B17,A3) + (A2-INDEX(A5:A17,A3)) * (INDEX(B5:B17,A3+1)-INDEX(B5:B17,A3)) / (INDEX(A5:A17,A3+1)-INDEX(A5:A17,A3))
B2: =ANSWER
```

[Excel Answer %](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIdYR.jpg)